# Code Splitting in Dart

Tags: dart

Is there any way to to some kind of code splitting in Dart? I'd like to defer the loading of some rarely used code to accelerate the initial code download. In Javascript, I'd inject a new `<script>` tag, in GWT i'd just call `GWT.runAsync()`. Is there something similar in Dart?

According to [this link](http://www.dartlang.org/articles/embedding-in-html/), `<script>` injection won't work ("Each HTML page can have at most one Dart script tag", "We do not support dynamically injecting a  tag that loads Dart code."). I also found [this fixed issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3819) claiming: "The initial one [use case] is deferred loading, to avoid massive downloads when some code is needed only later, or perhaps only needed in some situations. We now have a mechanism for this.". Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything on how to implement this. Does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update Sep 2014:** [this has been fixed!](http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html)

Dart now easily supports deferred loading with special `import... deferred` syntax. For example:

```
import analytics.dart deferred as analytics
void main(){
    analytics.loadLibrary.then((_) { // future
        // code ready
        enableAnalyticsControl()
    });
}
```

Here is [an official tutorial](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/deferred-loading.html) about using deferred loading.

---

I'm afraid what you're trying to do is still not possible (assuming you're not using dart2js that is) .

See [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10171).

> As Kasper said in comment 3, so far this has been discussed a deployment feature which you will get with dart2dart. The VMs involvement in supporting this ends with giving the dart2dart generated code access to loading sources lazily through a library call. This library API still needs to be specified though.

If you *are* using dart2js this can be done. [Here is a blog post on how to do this.](http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/lazy-load-libraries-in-dart.html)

```
const lazy = const DeferredLibrary('reverser', uri: './part.js');
```

Which will then let you call  `lazy.load().then((_) { ...`

Comment: I am using dart2js. But did I understand that right: At the moment, there can only be one split point? "[...] dart2js emits at most one other JavaScript file"

Comment: It's very recent and all still work in progress. I'm sorry but I don't know.

Comment: Alright, at least now i know what to look for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Correct, at the moment you can do up to one code split. See http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/lazy-load-libraries-in-dart.html

Comment: This is fixed http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html