# How can I execute two dart code in one HTML

Tags: dart, dart-async

I'm trying to build an Dart App.

This is the process that I would like to have.

At the first connection, the user have a loading page. During this time, he has an animation, and in background, the big dart file is downloaded (came from dart2js for dart).

Once it's over, the downloaded script is execute and the app cans start to work.

Any idea about the possibility of this process ?

Thank you.

EDIT:

```dart
import "dart:async";
@lazy
import 'test.dart' as foo;

const lazy = const DeferredLibrary('test');

void main() {
  foo.init(); // Supposed to throw a NoSuchMethodError.
  lazy.load().then(onFooLoaded);
}

void onFooLoaded(_) {
  foo.init();
}
```

test.dart

```dart
library test;

void init() {
  print("coucou");
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it works in Chrome but not in Dartium but needs a small change (see my updated answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called deferred loading. Basically this feature exists a while already but I haven't used it myself yet. Because of some open issues this feature seemed of limited use. I saw a notice that several bugs or missing feature were fixed but I can't tell the current status.

For more information see
- https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:async.DeferredLibrary
- http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/04/lazy-load-libraries-in-dart.html
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10171
- [Code Splitting in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378741/code-splitting-in-dart)
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3940
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=9483

#### Update

I tried it and it works in Chrome (not in Dartium) with a few small changes

test.dart

```dart
library some_lib_name; // <== was missing

void init() {
  print("coucou");
}
```

index.dart

```dart
const lazy = const DeferredLibrary('some_lib_name'); // use the library name not the file name
```

Comment: Thank you ! But I would like it work on Dartium... You have posted about this bug ?

Comment: As far as I have seen this is a known bug. It should be supported in dart2dart but this issue is still open. I haven't tried dart2dart but I think this doesn't work yet. Why do you need this in Dartium anyway?

Comment: Are you sure it works for you ? Because I still a problem, even with Chrome `Uncaught Deferred library test.dart was not loaded. `

Comment: At what line do you get this exception? Yes I'm sure it worked. With the line `foo.init();` I got an exception without it printed "coucou".

Comment: Sorry ... You're right (I feel a bit shameful...). In fact, the js code does not throw a NoSuchMethodError, but he does something like this error message :D

Comment: Nothing to worry, every developer knows that feeling to well ;-)