# Dart to js, files too large for mobile traffic in use with multi page web apps

Tags: dart, dart-html

The dart2js compiler makes js files too large for one single page,
for a smartphone that use mobile traffic is it useless when each page get a seperate *.dart.js file.
how can the size of multi-page web applications be reduced?
I think more than one page per dart js file is not possible or?

I thought something like that:

webapplication.dart.js
- index.dart(.js)
- faq.dart(.js)
- downloads.dart(.js)

but the dart files are compiled individually, and each file will be up to 200 KB with use different imports.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a website where each page is its own dart application.  This isn't ideal as you've noticed.  My recommendation would be to use [angular.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart) to create a single page application.

In either case, making sure your web server is gzipping content where appropriate (definitely any javascript files) can make a huge difference, as well as having proper caching headers.

Answer (score 2):

Dart supports deferred loading see [How can I execute two dart code in one HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827293)

As @w.brian said, different Dart applications for different pages doesn't make good use of Dart.
Dart has a big overhead to emulate functionality that JavaScript doesn't provide (for example classes).
The deployable packs all dependencies together and creates a single js file. The overhead is packed into every js file. This overhead alone is about 200k zipped. Your custom application code has to be rather complex to reach this size. Because this overhead is packed in a different file (combined with the custom code) it cannot   utilize the cache either.
This is just stroking Dart against the grain.
The bigger a Dart application becomes the less burden does this overhead become. With many small applications this is exactly the opposite.

Otherwise there are some things to notice:

When you build from DartEditor the default mode is 'debug' (not absolutely sure though). When you build from command line the default is 'release'. 'debug' mode produces larger output.

When you make use of the 'dart:mirrors' library you have to be careful. The er are certain considerations to make to ensure it doesn't bloat the JS output size.

And a few others things I probably didn't think of just now ...